# My Mapbox style can't be loaded in my angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to load a custom mapbox style I uploaded to the studio, into my angular app. It works perfectly using another style, being a factory mapbox style (i.e `mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11`) and another of my custom styles. But for some reasons, when trying to load [this particular style](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/elpierrot/ckl0qlk1q0skq17s0x0hhjli3.html?fresh=true&title=view&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZWxwaWVycm90IiwiYSI6ImNqeWN5dG5hazBuNzQzbW56bG92dTVjNWsifQ.jPVSyUfTZRwj_Gmvj2-DKQ): `mapbox://styles/elpierrot/ckl0qlk1q0skq17s0x0hhjli3`,
[nothing gets displayed on the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89WjF.png). 
The console gives me [those errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIx2i.png) when trying to load this style, and they don't occur when loading any other style. 
What I don't understand, is that when I try to load it in a jsfiddle, [it displays properly](https://jsfiddle.net/nicofeals/18njmke2/2/). I can also visualize the style in mapbox studio without any problem.
Here's the code:

```js
import { Map, LngLat, Marker } from 'mapbox-gl';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-asset-edition',
  templateUrl: './asset-edition.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./asset-edition.component.scss']
})

export class AssetEditionComponent implements OnInit {
  // Map
  map: Map;
  mapStyle: string = 'mapbox://styles/elpierrot/ckl0qlk1q0skq17s0x0hhjli3';
  mapCenter: LngLat | null;
  mapBounds: Array<LngLat> | null;
  coords: LngLat | null;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.coords = new LngLat(-65.017, -16.457);
    this.mapCenter = this.coords;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  ...
  <mgl-map [style]="mapStyle" [zoom]="[7]" [center]="mapCenter" [fitBounds]="mapBounds"
                        (load)="map = $event">
                    </mgl-map>
  ...
</div>
```

So is this a mapbox issue? Is there a problem with the style layers? (I can show my exact code if required, but as it works with another style it seems strange).

Comment: The image of Error you have attached and very first error  in console is showing the you are using wrong expression (unknown expression image..). Fix it first.

Comment: Well yeah that's what I'd like to do. The thing is the error doesn't seem to be originating from my code directly, I have no `image` expression, and the stacktrace reports it coming from mapbox and I can't get any info on what could be triggering it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Support for the "image" expression was added in [Mapbox GL JS 1.4.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#140), and upgrading to this version fixed the issue I had with loading a style containing satellite imagery.

Here's the error in text as I can't edit the original post:

```
`Unknown expression "image". If you wanted a literal array, use ["literal", [...]].`
```